# rapidxml throws exception on wchar_t content

Tags: c++, xml, windows, visual-c++, rapidxml

When parsing wchar_t content on win32 platform, rapidxml may throw parse_error exception. The content:

> `<xml att='最好' />`

Here is my testing code:

```
/*
 *  @file  : TestRapidXmlBug.cpp
 *  @author: shilyx
 *  @date  : 2015-09-16 11:02:22.886
 *  @note  : Generated by SlxTemplates
 */

#include <Windows.h>
#include "rapidxml.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace rapidxml;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // data block
    unsigned char szData[] = {
        0x3C, 0x00, 0x78, 0x00, 0x6D, 0x00, 0x6C, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x61, 0x00, 0x74, 0x00, 0x74, 0x00, 0x3D, 
        0x00, 0x27, 0x00, 0x00, 0x67, 0x7D, 0x59, 0x27, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x2F, 0x00, 0x3E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

    // uft8 string
    char szDataUtf8[sizeof(szData) * 10] = "";

    // ucs2 string
    wchar_t *szDataUcs2 = (wchar_t *)szData;

    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, szDataUcs2, -1, szDataUtf8, sizeof(szDataUtf8), NULL, NULL);

    try
    {
        xml_document<wchar_t> xml;

        cout<<"-------------------------wchar_t"<<endl;
        xml.parse<0>(szDataUcs2);  // will throw parse_error
        cout<<"success"<<endl;
    }
    catch (parse_error &ex)
    {
        cout<<"exception: "<<ex.what()<<endl;
        cout<<"failled"<<endl;
    }

    try
    {
        xml_document<char> xml;

        cout<<"-------------------------char"<<endl;
        xml.parse<0>(szDataUtf8);  // will not throw any exception
        cout<<"success"<<endl;
    }
    catch (parse_error &ex)
    {
        cout<<ex.what()<<endl;
        cout<<"failled"<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It will throw exception at:

```
        // Make sure that end quote is present
        if (*text != quote)
            RAPIDXML_PARSE_ERROR("expected ' or \"", text);
        ++text;     // Skip quote
```

The reason may be:

```
// Skip characters until predicate evaluates to true
template<class StopPred, int Flags>
static void skip(Ch *&text)
{
    Ch *tmp = text;
    while (StopPred::test(*tmp))
        ++tmp;
    text = tmp;
}
```

The StopPred::test function:

```
// Detect attribute value character
template<Ch Quote>
struct attribute_value_pure_pred
{
    static unsigned char test(Ch ch)
    {
        if (Quote == Ch('\''))
            return internal::lookup_tables<0>::lookup_attribute_data_1_pure[static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)];
        if (Quote == Ch('\"'))
            return internal::lookup_tables<0>::lookup_attribute_data_2_pure[static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)];
        return 0;       // Should never be executed, to avoid warnings on Comeau
    }
};
```

static_cast changes a wchar_t(0x6700) to unsigned char(0x00), the skip operation stopped.

---

Is this a bug? or a wrong to use rapidxml with wchar_t?
rapidxml's last update date is 2013-04-26, I think it should be stable enough.

Answer (score 1):

Rapidxml does not fully support UTF-16, UTF-32, or other wide encodings.

> Current version does not fully support UTF-16 or UTF-32, so use of wide characters is somewhat incapacitated. However, it should succesfully parse wchar_t strings containing UTF-16 or UTF-32 if endianness of the data matches that of the machine.

As you've seen, by an interesting coincidence the character `0x6700` when converted to an `unsigned char` for rapidxml's internal table lookup is `0`, which is not a valid attribute character and so terminates the parsing. I suppose the documentation should clarify that partial support for wide encoding is available with the caveat that you do not use code points outside Basic Latin and Latin-1 (i.e. U+0000 ~ U+00FF).

The solution is to use UTF-8 instead.

Comment: Thank you, but I can not use utf-8 instead here. I found that there is no problem with rapidxml.hpp in boost, maybe I should choose that version. Thanks.

Comment: @shilyx I doubt that will change anything, as far as I can tell boost property_tree uses rapidxml under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to put and extend shilyx's comment as an answer - boost really have modified rapidxml.hpp which has following fix:

```
template<class Ch>
inline size_t get_index(const Ch c)
{
    // If not ASCII char, its semantic is same as plain 'z'.
    // char could be signed, so first stretch and make unsigned.
    unsigned n = c;
    if (n > 127)
    {
        return 'z';
    }
    return c;
}

...

return internal::lookup_tables<0>::lookup_attribute_data_1_pure[internal::get_index(ch)];
```

So, all the characters higher than 127 are threated as 'z'.